# Static local variable and auto

Tags: c++

In the code snippet below, is the local variarble result1 static? Is the keyword static mandatory do declare a static local variable or would auto suffice?

```
static int ExpensiveInit() {
 ...
}


class Foo {
 void Bar() {
   auto result1 = ExpensiveInit(); 
   static int result2 = ExpensiveInit();
   ...
 }
}
```

Comment: `auto` is a type specifier, not a storage one

Comment: `ExpensiveInit` is a static function that returns an int. It isn't a function that returns a static int.

Comment: Also first `static` has different meaning then second one. First one means "this symbols (function) should be visible only in this translation unit".

Comment: Also the meaning of `static` in `static int ExpensiveInit()`, assuming it's a free function, is extremely different from the meaning of `static` in `static int result2`, a local function variable. The former means `ExpensiveInit` has internal linkage, the latter means that there is only one instance of `result2` shared between different invocations of `Foo::Bar`.

Comment: C++ has quite a few keywords and operators that have different semantics in different contexts.  `static` is one such keyword.  (This is one of the features of C++ that makes the language more confusing and difficult to learn.)

Comment: `static` is not a part of the type system. There is no such thing as a `static int` type. So `static` can't be deduced by `auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a class attribute `static` when you want all instances of your class to share the same value of this variable, it is useful to count how many instances of a class you have for example.

Therefore by stating

```
static int count = 4;
```

As an attribute of your class, every instance will have access to this variable, and if an instance increment `count`, it will increment this variable for other instances aswell

Auto declaration means that the type of variable will be automaticaly assigned by the compiler, as long as it is coherent.

If you state :

```
auto hello = "Hello";
```

Hello is considered as a String

Thus, no, result1 is not Static in your example, it is a simple int, in wich is copied the value returned by expensiveInit()